# Why don't tanks have radar aimed guns?

Tags: military, combat

After World War II, plenty of radar aimed guns were developed for the purpose of targeting the guns of anti-aircraft vehicles.

Why hasn't this same technology been applied to tanks? A 900 MHz radar unit would operate on a wavelength of 33.3 cm. This seems like it would be more than accurate enough to aim the main tank of a gun.

I would also think that a tank would be an excellent target with lots of strong radar returns. Some tanks have rounded turrets, but there is usually something flat with hard edges that should show up on radar.

The output would need to be fed into a gun computer to calculate an aiming solution, but those have been around for quite some time.

Comment: The USSR experimented with radar-aimed guns on the [T-10 tank](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UzAqDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA159&lpg=PA159&dq=soviet+T-10+tank+radar&source=bl&ots=ivJhE8UopG&sig=qi4mQGbPPYW5ff5SVFEZ1Sp0_Mg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYk_HHwJ7WAhUFJlAKHbwIDn0Q6AEIXTAJ#v=onepage&q=soviet%20T-10%20tank%20radar&f=false) in the late 1950s & early 1960s

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because discussion of hypothetical situations/ weapon systems *not* developed is not History.

Comment: @user2448131, the question is quite answerable if anyone started a research project and then abandoned it after finding the idea was unworkable for one reason or another.

Comment: This question would benefit from preliminary research (as sempaiscuba points out).

Comment: Some use infra red as it's a a better choice. A hot tank engine show up as a bright spot against the colder environment.

Comment: @liftarn thermal imaging is used for general vision purposes as it helps tank crews see through smoke - though the lasers used are probably IR, too, the thermal imaging is not used for aiming the gun.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Radar is great at detecting objects in the sky or silhouettes on the horizon - so it is perfect for anti-aircraft and anti-ship gun aiming.

However, tanks are almost never in the sky, and should never be silhouetted. Picking tanks against the ground is troublesome.

Radar systems up into the 1960/70s were quite cumbersome - anti-aircraft batteries tended to be static emplacements. As the the USAF got better at suppressing air defence in Vietnam, the Russians developed mobile units - but the radar was still quite cumbersome, using a separate truck or trailer to the launchers. Ships don't have a problem with tucking a large radar system somewhere on board, but tanks have limited space and engine power (therefore, weight limits - adding radar would have meant less armour, or less ammunition, or something else being taken out).

Another downside is that the tank would have to be radiating in order to get a return - which is what the USAF targeted when they developed air defence supression tactics - they went for the AA radars. By using radar, you've now made your tank an even bigger target.

Modern tanks (M1 Abrams, Challenger 2, Leopard 2, etc) are using laser targeting systems now - the gunner sights the target, and the turret and gun automatically rotate and elevate accordingly. With auto-stabilisation, it is even possible for these tanks to fire accurately on the move (and at a fair clip). I'm not sure when the laser technology was introduced - but it seems to be at least 30 years old. Focused lasers are lot less detectable than radar (you're more likely to detect the scatter from the target than the source).

So - short answer: radar was too big to be used on a tank, and when it started getting small enough, it was superceded.

Comment: According to the [Wikipedia article] (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centurion_(tank)) the 1948 Centurion Mark III tank had "a fully automatic stabilisation system for the gun, allowing it to fire accurately while on the move".

Comment: @kimchilover - true, auto-stablisation has been around a long while - but this was assistive technology supporting the gunner as he aimed the gun. The modern laser aiming systems mean that the turret movement itself can be fully automated.

Comment: Of course they are better now.   In 1948 there were no lasers.  I was just refining on your "at least 30 years" comment.  I should have qualified with something like "some form of this technology ..."

Comment: @kimchilover Ah, I see - sorry, I added the auto-stabilisation thing and left the "this technology" in the next sentence causing ambiguity - fixed now.

Comment: I would add just one point, that this answer implies, that the tank could have a need for the radar in order to target other tanks. But according to some generals, like Guderian, the main target for the tanks is infantry, and the situation where tanks are forced to fight other tanks is undesirable

Comment: @user907860 - a fair point, tank doctrine has evolved since WWII and Guderian, however. And I think the massed tank battles of the Eastern Front also blew holes through Guderian's ideal

Comment: @HorusKol The fact that massive tank battles happened doesn't necessarily mean that the tank's main objective should be fighting other tanks. In modern combat doctrine, tanks are usually thought to be easier to deal with by air forces in the open or by infantry with personal AT weapons in urban/mountainous terrain. I'm not saying tanks can't kill other tanks, far from it; they are just usually not the most efficient way to do it.